# API Mechanisms for Crypto Asset Transfer on Tron and BNB Blockchains

Tags: wallets, json-rpc, bsc, transfers-api, tron

I have experience using the Bitcoin RPC API, which provides the capability to create applications that can communicate with the Bitcoin network. This includes the development of self-custody wallets, block explorers, and a variety of other services and tools that are based on blockchain technology.

I’m interested in understanding if similar mechanisms exist on other blockchains, specifically Tron and BNB. Is there a way to directly call the blockchain for crypto asset transfers via an API on these platforms?

Any insights or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. There are libraries like web3/etherjs and there are programmable smart contract.